# Why refer to alcoholic beverages as Yash?

Tags: words, pronunciation, food

In many Chasidishe and Heimishe Shuls - Vodka, Whiskey and the likes are known as "Yash" which is an acronym for Yayin Saraf - `יי״ש`. However would it not be more appropiate to call it Yas? Then why do we call it Yash?

Comment: I think it appears in Halacha books (e.g. Chayei Adam) as יי״ש

Comment: It is actually an acronym and not some Germanic word, right?

Comment: We do call the Sifsei Kohen the Shach, not the Shak., for example (like Dave's answer).

Comment: @ba or better yet, the Sak (sifsei, not shifsei)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess because it is relatively uncommon for the letter Sin to appear at the end of a word, so the "natural" reading is Yash. Or, it could be that some people thought the second letter represented "Sheichar" rather than "Saraf," and their mispronunciation caught on.

Answer (score 4):

A friend of mine just told me, "well the guy drunk a bit and is mixed up".

Comment: Very funny! Or maybe the originators of the term were Litvaks...