# Difficult phrases in the "Sale of Chametz" document

Tags: words, translation, yiddish, selling-mechirat-chametz

I am currently working on a clarification of the document which is usually used by rabbis to sell chametz to a non-Jew. The version I am working with is that of [Harav hagGaon Avraham Aharon Yudelewitz Zatzal](http://www.yu.edu/riets/about/mission-history/historic-roshei/avraham-aharon-yudelowitz/), (author of [Shu"t Bet Av](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=577&pgnum=1)), which is sprinkled with Yiddish phrases. I am having difficulty translating  most of them, and I was hoping the community can help me translate them into Hebrew so that the document can be better understood by non-Yiddish readers. Here are the difficult phrases.

- ומסרתי לו שטר הלז שיקנה את החדר הנ"ל בשלימות בשכירות גם בשטר הלז וגם **בהאנדשלאג**  שעשיתי עמו (I think this one means a handshake)
- (In a list of items being sold:) וכל מיני **סארטין מנאליווקעס**
- וכל מיני **יי"ג** (I think its some form of wine)
- או משקה של חומץ ושמרים ו**מאלץ**
- וכל מיני **גרויפין** וקמחים של חמץ
- ואפילו אם נעשו לרפואה כגון **ארסיקלען שבדרוג משארס**
- תחלת דמי הפרעון הנקרא **אופגאב** (down payment?)
- וגם עשיתי **צושלאג** עם הא''י הנ''ל על שכירת המקומות הנ''ל
- ודמי זמן "**הנאטיס**" כפי הנהוג במדינה זו ישלם מכיסו (possibly a typo - original is hard to read here)

These are the phrases I am having difficulty with, and can at best guess based out of context, but I would feel much more comfortable revising the contract on solid footing.

---

**Edit:** [Here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3IMXkQ55QdsVGpta0xvaTJTRTZCYU9RSlZ4OEdvdw) is my current version of the whole contract. Very few changes have been made from the original. (FTR, this is not a finalized document.)

Comment: **[asked with permission](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/953/1172)**

Comment: Welcome back I'. Great to see you.

Comment: Which country was this used in? And could you post an image of the original?

Comment: Also - try Google Translate: http://translate.google.com/#yi|en|

Comment: If you can post the original it would be easier to translate as some of these may be off by a letter or so.

Comment: דרוג משארס = drug measurers (or mixers)?

Comment: I will B"H post the original and my working version when I have access to a scanner. I dont know what country it was used in or much about the author, but if it helps there is a line which says something along the lines of *"and [the non-Jew] may translate this document into English"*

Comment: google translate translates yiddish as one of its languages.

Comment: Google's not very good with yiddish. Here's a pretty decent online dictionary: http://www.yiddishdictionaryonline.com/

Comment: I don't know how accurately i can identify these phrases in a bilingual dictionary when i dont know one of the languages at all. also, I'm not so sure a dictionary can capture the context and connotations as well as actual native speakers.

Comment: Now that I think about it, ארסיקלען שבדרוג משארס is probably ארטיקלען שבדרוג סטארס = *articles (items) in drug stores.*

Comment: @Dave can that last word possibly be referring to some sort of container used to store medication? I think it fits better in context with the rest of that part of the document (which is now linked to in the question BTW)

Comment: Community wiki?

Comment: @l' - actually I think my suggestion is perfect in context.

Comment: The word מנאליווקעס is really vexing. It's either a bad copying error, or some kind of Russian (?) word.

Comment: he doesn't have a Sharir Vekayam?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill they stick that in the end of a ketuba, right? The phrase sounds familiar...

Comment: @l' It is in the Ksuva.

Comment: @Dave you were right about my typo in "drug stores" (although I my defense that word was quite incoherent).

Answer (score 3):

או משקה של חומץ ושמרים ו***מאלץ*** = **Malt**

וגם עשיתי **צושלאג** עם הא''י הנ''ל על שכירת המקומות הנ''ל = I also made a **further agreement** with the non Jew on the rental of the above listed locations.

Comment: I think it's "a further agreement" or "an additional agreement", that's the "tzu" part; right?

Comment: wow, was that really neccesary to have been written in Yiddish? you'd think Yiddish would be used for expressions which are hard to say in hebrew.... are there any connotations which that phrase carry??

Comment: There is no reason all of it can not be written in Hebrew unless in those days there was no Hebrew words for these items.

Comment: @Shalom: not necessarily; "tzu" can also correspond to English "to" (as in צוריק, "to the back" or "backwards").

Answer (score 3):

סארטין מנאליווקעס seems to mean "sorts (types) of liqueur" - *nalivka* being the Russian word for [a beverage of that type](http://www.ruscuisine.com/recipes/beverages-and-drinks/n--107/), some formulations of which, I guess, might contain chametz.

I think that Dave is correct that ארסיקלען שבדרוג משארס should be ארטיקלען שבדראג סטארס - articles (items) in drugstores.

הנאטיס, as I mentioned in a comment, I think simply means "the notice." (The context is that the non-Jewish buyer may hire other people to run the business during Pesach, so presumably he'd have to put up notices advertising the position.)

I think the rest of them are pretty well covered.

Comment: Can you confirm that אופגאב is a down payment? It fits in context

Comment: It is. See [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38428&pgnum=132), for example: בערבון, ר"ל דמי קדימה (אופגאב בלע"ז)... כמו סוחר הקונה סחורה בכמה אלפים ונותן מעות קדימה.

Comment: Ah, so there was an extra מ there! Google translates nalivka as liquor, brandy, or cordial (http://translate.google.com/#ru|en|%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: @Dave: the מ isn't really extra - it's the usual use of that prefix in Hebrew (hence my translation of it as "of").

Answer (score 2):

**גרויפין** usually means "gravel." In this context I'd assume "any grains or flours of chametz."

Any chance it's a typo and **יי"ג** should be **יי"ש**? [That means liquor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/the-term-yash).

I agree that the first one is a handshake. (Funny as rabbinic Hebrew has a word for it: תקיעת כף)

Comment: no, both **יי"ש** and **יי"ג** are in the document. i was told that יי"ש is יין שרף and im guessing that this is something similar.

Comment: יי"ג = יין גפן (grape wine, presumably that which might contain admixtures of chometz)

Comment: גרויפין actually means something like coarsely milled beans or grain. See Seder Birchos Hanehenin (by the Baal Hatanya), [7:22 and 24](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&pgnum=483), and his Shulchan Aruch, [Orach Chaim 202:17](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/sh/sh1/18/202/17). Could be that they were so called because they resembled gravel, though.

Comment: @Alex sounds to me like someone knows Yiddish well enough for a comprehensive answer...

Comment: @l', so far Shalom and Dave and Gershon (and you, with your suggested translations) have done a pretty good job with most of it. I'm not sure about nos. 2 and 9 - it'll definitely help to see the original - although הנאטיס might be exactly what it sounds like, "the notice."

Comment: @Alex the retyped version I provide in the question is almost word for word from the original. questionable phrases are marked in read. (Typos may exist because the original was over-copied and hard to read, especially the letters ה ח נ and ג, but I'm hoping they can be fixed based on context.)